# Integrate Microsoft AX dynamics 2012 r3 in web app

Tags: php, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I develop an ERP software using PHP. Now I want to integrate  Microsoft AX dynamics 2012 r3 in my app as per client need. Since I am a PHP developer I am confused on how to get started. On exploring, I came to know that the best way to integrate it through web service

How do I create web services for  AX?
Extensibility of available services .
I couldn't find a good resource for this in the web. So can anyone suggest good resources or which is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"I came to know that the best way to integrate it through web service"_ - I'm guessing that it's Soap? Then read up on Soap and make some attempts. Just a heads up, asking for off-site resources is off-topic here on SO and will most likely get your question closed.

Answer (score 3):

An excellent place to start would be the official documentation for integrating with Dynamics AX 2012 found [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/integration-with-microsoft-dynamics-ax).

A tool that you might want to use is the Application Integration Framework (AIF services). You can either integrate with out of the box services developed by Microsoft, or create your own services. This will require knowledge of AX and X++. You could then expose and call these services from your PHP application. To begin with AIF, go [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/services-and-application-integration-framework-aif) for the main page, which has architectural and planning documentation and [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/creating-new-document-services) for a more specific documentation on (document) service development. For exposing these services via what are called "adapters", look at the links at the top of [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/appuser-itpro/services-and-aif-operations) page. You may be interested in the HTTP adapter for example, to expose your service in that manner.

Another option could be to create your own services in PHP and call them from AX. You could call the services from X++, but due to the limitations of the language this is sometimes easier achieved by calling the services you created in PHP from a C# library. The C# library would use proxy classes to call X++ objects to read/write whatever data you are getting/posting to/from your PHP services. [**This**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/proxy-classes-for-net-interop-to-x) and [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/integration-with-x-objects-from-visual-studio) may be interesting starting points for documentation on how to do that.

Getting the know the Dynamics AX specific terminology by reading these docs can help with your google-fu later on during development... but once you get a feel for the terms there is a lot more info on forums and whatnot that you'll be able to find.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. I have done that. On a high level overview, There are 2 ends in this task.
1. PHP side
2. Dynamics AX 2012 side
And you need to connect both sides with each other.

For PHP end, if you are using any framework or PHP without any framework, you need to write a RESTful web service that can send request and receive response.
For Dynamics AX 2012, you need to write a web service that can request and receive response. 
The both end points used in web service will do the job.